# How do I use logical operators to convert numeric vector to binary?

Tags: r

How do I use logical expressions to convert numeric vector into binary? Numeric vector (1,2,3,4) into 1 to "TRUE", 2 to "TRUE", 3 to "FALSE" .

Comment: `vec < 3` or even `vec <= 2`

Comment: Could you be more specific about the context? As it stands, one could do any number of things, which are all useless under slightly different conditions: `as.logical(vec - 3)` will give your desired results if (and only if) `vec` is `c(1, 2, 3, 4)` and (as indicated in your question) you don't care about `4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may use `%in%` to create a logical vector

```
v1 %in% 1:2
```

Comment: v1 %in% 1:2 works well.    v1 %in% 1 returns TRUE FALSE but when I apply as.integer(as.logical(v1)) or as.numeric(v1) it only returns 1 instead of 1,0.  What could be the problem?

Comment: @user17122732 it returns 1 for 1 value and other values will be 0 when you do `v1 %in% 1`